# How to put a footnote in a figure caption without it showing up on \listofffigures?

Tags: table-of-contents, graphics, captions, footnotes

I know this topic has been talked about in this forum extensively but I don't seem to find a good answer. To get a footnote on a caption of a figure the only way that I've been really satisfied been with has been something like this:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{name.png}
    \caption{caption \protect\footnotemark}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{source}

\end{document}
```

However when using `\listoffigures` the footnotes are still there and not only the caption. Is there a easy way to get around this problem and really have just the caption in the list of figures?

Comment: `\caption[text for lof]{text with \footnotemark}`